# Android ListView : can't see a simple list

Tags: java, android, listview

This is probably twick I'm missing, pls assist

I've create a simple list and bind it to an adapter

but for some reason It ain't showing when running on device

this is align with all tutorials I've come across with

fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingTop="4dip"
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:weightSum="1.0"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView android:id="@+id/singName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="LOGO"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/messagesList"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/singName" />
```

Java:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.messagesList);

    String [] messages = new String[]{
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4"
    };


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.message_item,
            messages);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

message_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/message_item_text">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Is `fragment.xml` really named `fragment_main.xml` like the one you're inflating?

Comment: Yes it is fragment_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you inflater `fragment_main.xml` twice. You have to fix that and return the first View. Other than that what's the problem does it crash or what?

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.messagesList);

    String [] messages = new String[]{
            "Item 1", 
            "Item 2", 
            "Item 3", 
            "Item 4" 
    }; 


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(), 
            R.layout.message_item,
            messages);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

You posted your `fragment.xml` file but you are inflating `fragment_main.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks 
I've fix the duplication but that wasn't the issue
The list just not showing - no crashing

I've found the issue - i should set the adapter on onActivityCreated method instead of onCreateView since i'm working with fragment

Comment: Yes, that was one of the issues. You were setting ListView of the layout that you didn't use. Now you can update your code and problem what is the problem or if you get any error.

Comment: @HaimS8 You should give Sharj some credit here since that was a major mistake in your original code and likely the cause of your problem. Moving the adapter to `onAcitivtyCreated` alone doesn't really make sense to solve your problem and it is not a requirement to set it there.

Comment: Setting adapter in `onAcitivtyCreated` is optional. It should work in `onCreateView ` as well if there are no other issues and you are setting the adapter on correct ListView.

Comment: Thanks Sharj !
All the credit to U as long as the problem solved :)